# Gulp minify Angular.js & it's modules

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have a gulp script that minifies my javascript:

```
gulp.task("min:js",
    function() {
        return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs])
            .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
    });
```

When it minifies

```
<script src="Scripts/Min/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Min/main.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Min/angular.js"></script>
```

That seems to work, but when I try to minify

```
<script src="Scripts/Min/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Min/main.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Min/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Min/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

I get angular is not defined in my console and the site doesn't come up.

I'm relatively new to gulp and angular, am I missing something here?

Update
Paths:

```
paths.concatJsDest = "Scripts/site.min.js";
paths.js = "Scripts/Min/**/*.js";
```

Comment: Please, share your app module in `main.js`, not all of its content. There may lie the problem.

Comment: main.js != app.js it's just some javascript for bootstrap fixed menu.  Once I get a handle on my base script libraries minification's I'll move onto minifying my Angular app and controller w ngAnnote.

Comment: I mean, sometimes, when you minify or uglify an angular file, if you do not use `$inject`, like `(function(){ MyController.$inject = ['$scope']; function MyController($scope){} })();` it may lose dependencies cause of renaming process made by them. I'm saying this since I lost quite time finding why I got your same error some time ago.

Comment: Show us the order in which you are feeding the files to gulp. Also, if your code is not monkey-patched you are better off using mangle: false

Comment: @yBrodsky looks like it was the order, the min file was being generated with the angular module before angular causing the undefined I believe.  I took the angular file out and put all the modules in, I don't want to manually specify the order for each file, do I need to take another step to replace angular.js with angular.js.min or is there a better solution?

Comment: What you need to do is specify the order for the files that require so. It will be the easiest way. Angular main file will come first, then the different modules. I can show you an example if you need to, but I think its clear

Comment: No need, I got it, thanks! Feel free to post your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept. I also posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I've narrowed my problem down to file order, I can use gulp-htmlreplace to load angular.min.js first:

```
<!--build:angular-->
<script src="Scripts/Src/angular.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js -->
<script src="Scripts/Min/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Min/main.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Min/loading-bar.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Min/angular-ui-router.js"></script>/script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And the gulp steps:

```
    gulp.src('Index.html')
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            js: paths.concatJsDest,
            angular: paths.angularmin
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
gulp.task("min:js",
    function() {
        return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs])
            .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
    });
```

My consideration is that I'll be adding many more modules to my angular as I build out the site, so a static order isn't ideal.